# if statement breaking .push method

Tags: javascript, if-statement, push, each

So I'm looping through a set of JSON arrays, and then looping through each individual array.

If I remove the two if statements it will loop through both data sets and append the 'target' with both 'data' sets, but like it is now, it will only append the items.join through the first each loop.

The case stuff was an if loop first, thinking it would matter, but no.

Strange thing is, the consoleOut (like console.log) does print my stuff, so It actually does loop through both arrays within the JSON set.

```
    $.each(data, function(keys, vals)
    {

    var items = [];


     $.each(data[keys], function(key, val) 
     {

        var currString = JSON.stringify(val);
        switch (key)
        {
        case "ID":              
            consoleOut("ID: "+currString+" loaded");
        break;                                      

        case "parentIDs":

            consoleOut("parentIDs: "+currString);
        break;
        case "UID":
            consoleOut("UID: "+currString);
            UID = unquote(currString);
        break;
        case "title":
            consoleOut("Title: "+currString);
            items.push('<H1 class="' + key + '">' + unquote(currString) + '</H1>');
        break;
        case "img":
            consoleOut("IMG: "+currString);

            if ($(currString).val() !== '')
            {
            items.push('<IMG class="' + key + '" src='+currString+'></IMG>');               
            };
        break;
        case "text":
            consoleOut("TXT: "+currString);

            if ($(currString).val() !== '')
            {
            items.push('<P class="' + key + '">'+currString+'</P>');

            };
        break;
        }
      });
      consoleOut("---------");

      $('<DIV/>', {
        'id': UID,
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo(target);
    } 
)
```

I'm wondering how the if statements are breaking my appending to the main 'items' array..

(When I don't stringify the val at the beginning it will loop, but that's because the if statements are then true, but stop working when false.. So maybe It's better to modify my if statement for that, but I'm still puzzled as to how the .push stops working?)

Comment: try changing `!==` to `!=` to see if it works!

Comment: is it possible for you to setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @linuxeasy learn what !== and === is. [I see your deleted post ;)]

Comment: @epascarello I know the what these are, but I thought these are only available in PHP, and the OP has copied this habit from PHP, but later while searching I realized that its available in Javascript too :D, thats why deleted it :)

Comment: can't get the JSON Object to work in fiddle... I'm getting it as an object from PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(currString).val()
```

It is saying you are making an element and looking at the value attribute of that element. Is that what you really want? I do not think image or text has a value.

I would think you would want to use length or html()

[EDIT] Looking at your object, you just want to check the lenght of currString

```
if( currString && currString.length>0 ) {
```

Comment: Its hard to tell when we don't have the JSON.

Comment: [{"ID":"1","parentIDs":null,"UID":"home","title":"Home","text":"<3 here","img":"/favicon.ico","url":"home","cat_id":"1","view_id":"","css_id":null},{"ID":"4","parentIDs":"home","UID":"home_info","title":"Info about Home","text":"Info about Home","img":"","url":"","cat_id":"","view_id":"","css_id":null}]

Comment: I tried .length != 0, to no avail. I just want to skip the .push when the "" is empty...

Comment: `currString` in a boolean context already implies that it's not an empty string.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but it would return true, because it was "", but I think I just shouldn't have stringified the stuff, anyway, I now have defaulted empty fields to NULL so I can check for that..

Answer (score 0):

This is not JSON, it is an array.

```
[{"ID":"1",
  "parentIDs":null,
  "UID":"home",
  "title":"Home",
  "text":"<3 here",
  "img":"/favicon.ico",
  "url":"home",
  "cat_id":"1",
  "view_id":"",
  "css_id":null}‌​,
 {"ID":"4",
  "parentIDs":"home",
  "UID":"home_info",
  "title":"Info about Home",
  "text":"Info about Home",
  "img":"",
  "url":"",
  "cat_id":"",
  "view_id":"",
  "css_id":null}
]
```

Are you sure your input does not look something like this (ie, is JSON)?

```
{ "data" : [{"ID":"1",
             "parentIDs":null,
             "UID":"home",
             "title":"Home",
             "text":"<3 here",
             "img":"/favicon.ico",
             "url":"home",
             "cat_id":"1",
             "view_id":"",
             "css_id":null}‌​,
            {"ID":"4",
             "parentIDs":"home",
             "UID":"home_info",
             "title":"Info about Home",
             "text":"Info about Home",
             "img":"",
             "url":"",
             "cat_id":"",
             "view_id":"",
             "css_id":null}
           ] }
```